# can editing one record in a table edit a record in other table

Tags: ms-access

So I have two tables: One for my patients **(patientsT)**, and the other table for the follow up of my patients **(PatientFollowupT)**..

In the 1st one I have a checkbox field for whether patient need follow up or not. The patientID is the primary key.

In the 2nd one I have a checkbox field to discharge the patient and stop the follow up. In this table I have no primary key as the pt may need more than one follow up visit - each in a single record.

Then I created a query from the 1st table to show only patients who need follow up, through the checkbox field.

With that I created two forms for data entry for both tables.
Now the 1st form **PatientsF** is completely fine and have no issues...

In the 2nd form **PatientFollowupF**, I have a combo box that displays the query, to choose from and add a record in the **patientfollowupT** accordingly.

Till here everything is fine, and when I need to discharge the patient, I click on the discharge check box.

So my question is: how can I update the value of the checkbox in the 1st table automatically when I click on the discharge checkbox of the 2nd table.

I think you can see why ?
because i need the combo box to be updated only with active patients to follow up.

I tried so many codes, but I'm really unable to find a solution :(

help me please ...

Comment: You run an UPDATE query: `CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE patientsT SET Discharge = True WHERE patientID=" & Me.PatientID`